# Github action execute an action that calls other actions upon its completion

Tags: github, build, yaml, action, github-actions

I have to do the following, every time a commit is done (so it can also be done by editing the file from the browser on Github), a `Github action` is called.

The `Github action` has to do the following:
Run the command found in the `package.json` or just run the `ncc build` command

What such a thing:

```
"build": "ncc build"
```

To then commit the build files.

After committing with the push, the `4 Github action test` must be run.

How do you advise me to do?

I thought of such a thing:

```yaml
on:
  push:
    branches:
      - master
  
name: Build
jobs:
  build:
    name: Build
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2
        name: Check out current commit
         
      - name: Install
        run: npm install

      - name: Build
        run: npm run build 
          
      - name: Commit
        run: |
         git config --local user.email "41898282+github-actions[bot]@users.noreply.github.com"
         git config --local user.name "github-actions[bot]"
         git add .
         git commit -m "Build" -a
         
      - name: Push
        uses: ad-m/github-push-action@master
        with:
         github_token: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}
         branch: ${{ github.ref }}
```

At the moment the test is like this for example, how can I do?

Test.yml

```yaml
on:
  push:
    branches:
      - master

name: "Testing"

jobs:
  test_the_action:
    name: Test the action
    runs-on: ubuntu-18.04
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2          
      - uses: suisei-cn/actions-download-file@master
        id: downloadfile
        name: Download a file
        with:
          url: "[API Endpoint](https://api.github.com/repos/suisei-cn/actions-download-file)"
          target: public/
          auto-match: true

      - name: Display the file
        run: head -n8 public/actions-download-file
```

Answer (score 1):

There are two options. You can add jobs for each test in your main yml with the [needs](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions#jobsjob_idneeds) keyword or call your test yml with the [workflow run](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/events-that-trigger-workflows#workflow_run) event as trigger.

**Option 1 with needs keyword:**

```
on:
  push:
    branches:
      - master
  
name: Build
jobs:
  build:
    name: Build
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - <your-build-steps>
  test1:
    name: Test
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    needs: build
    steps:
      - <your-test-steps>
```

**Option 2 with workflow run as trigger:**

```
on:
  workflow_run:
    workflows: ["<name-of-your-main-workflow>"]
    types:
      - completed

name: "Testing"

jobs:
  test_the_action:
```

This option works only on default branch.